# An alternative proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

I can't fill the details of the following proof :

***Theorem*** : $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed.

**Proof** : Let $E$ a finite extension of $\Bbb C$. Then, the map $ f : E^* \ni z \mapsto z^2$ is a covering. $E^*$ is connected and simply connected, so we have a degree $2$ cover which is trivial and non-trivial, contradiction.

I don't know why $f$ is a covering, and I don't even know if the map is surjective. If both of these facts are true this is ok. If $f$ is a cover but not surjective, I don't know how to interpret the rest of the argument. Apparently the argument is due to Hopf. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: @JulianRosen : I completely changed my question, hoping this is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ is a finite extension field of $\mathbb{C}$. The multiplication of $E$ should be bilinear on $E$ as vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and commutative. Surjectivity means existence of square roots. $2$-covering should refer to that the preimage of a small neighborhood $U$ of any nonzero element in $E$ has two disjoint copies of open sets such that each of them is homeomorphic to $U$ under square map, where you choose $U$ to be small enough.

Comment: Simply this, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a covering, the exact sequence  of Serre gives:

$\pi_1(F)\rightarrow \pi_1(E)\rightarrow \pi_1(A)\rightarrow \pi_0(F)\rightarrow 1$, since $E$ is simpy connected, $\pi_1(E)=1$, we deduce that $\pi_1(A)\rightarrow \pi_0(F)$ is an isomorphism, since $\pi_0(F)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, we deduce that $A$ is not simply connected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not exactly what I was expected, but I did realize the question could be written in a confusing way, I did edit my question. Thanks again.